# On insert, output columns that wern't inserted but in joined tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert

I'm currently working on some kind of data mapping. Lets say I have the following three tables:

**TemporaryTable**

```
RUNID | DocId | Amount
E       7       50
C       6       12
```

**Table1**

```
T1ID | DocID | Amount
1      5       10
2      6       20
3      6       50
```

**Table2**

```
T2ID | RUNID | T1Id
1      B       1
2      C       2
3      D       3
```

In table `Table1` and `Table2` the columns `T1ID` and `T2ID` are identity columns that are populated automatically.
What I want to do now is to insert the values from `TemporaryTable` into `Table1` and save the value in column `RunID` from `TemporaryTable` and the newly generated `T1ID` to `Table2`

The resulting table should look like this:

**Table1**

```
T1ID | DocID | Amount
1      5       10
2      6       20
3      6       50
4      7       50
5      6       12
```

**Table2**

```
T2ID | RUNID | T1Id
1      B       1
2      C       2
3      D       3
4      E       4
5      C       5
```

I would like to do so with the help of the `output` statement. Something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #map(T1ID, RUNID)
INSERT INTO Table1(DocId, Amount)
OUTPUT inserted.T1ID, t.RunId INTO #map 
SELECT t.DocId, t.Amount
FROM TemporaryTable t
```

This obviously doesn't work since I have no access to t.RunId in the output statement. How could this be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [MERGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql) command with some always-false condition to simulate your insert with all columns available in `OUTPUT`

```
MERGE Table1 t1
USING TemporaryTable t
  ON 1=2
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (DocId, Amount)
  VALUES (t.DocId, t.Amount)
  OUTPUT inserted.T1ID, t.RunId 
  INTO #map ;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Finally a real benefit of MERGE!